# Lambda Expression for find_if

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to find an element in vector V. 
but i get a lot of errors.

bool VNS::remove(const HostName& name){
      ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/algorithm:62:0,
                 from vns.cc:2:.....

```
 bool VNS::remove(const HostName& name){
        auto it=find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const HostName& a, const HostName& b){return a==b;});
        //code that will remove the elem.
        if(it!=v.end()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
HeaderFile:
class VNS:public NameServerInterface{
    public:
        /*
         * Insert a name/address pair. Does not check if the name
         * or address already exists.
         */
        virtual void insert(const HostName&, const IPAddress&);

        /*
         * Remove the pair with the specified host name. Returns true
         * if the host name existed and the pair was removed, false
         * otherwise.
         */
        virtual bool remove(const HostName&);

        /*
         * Find the IP address for the specified host name. Returns
         * NON_EXISTING_ADDRESS if the host name wasn't in the name
         * server.
         */
        virtual IPAddress lookup(const HostName&) const;

    private:
        std::vector<std::pair<HostName,IPAddress> > v;
};
```

Interface:

```
/*
 * Interface NameServerInterface -- all name server implementations must
 * implement this interface.
 */
#ifndef NAME_SERVER_INTERFACE_H
#define NAME_SERVER_INTERFACE_H

#include <string>

using HostName = std::string;
using IPAddress = unsigned int;
const IPAddress NON_EXISTING_ADDRESS = 0;

class NameServerInterface {
public:
    virtual ~NameServerInterface() = default;

    /*
     * Insert a name/address pair. Does not check if the name
     * or address already exists.
     */
    virtual void insert(const HostName&, const IPAddress&) = 0;

    /*
     * Remove the pair with the specified host name. Returns true
     * if the host name existed and the pair was removed, false
     * otherwise.
     */
    virtual bool remove(const HostName&) = 0;

    /*
     * Find the IP address for the specified host name. Returns
     * NON_EXISTING_ADDRESS if the host name wasn't in the name
     * server.
     */
    virtual IPAddress lookup(const HostName&) const = 0;
};

#endif
```

My lambda exp has two parameters. How will the compiler know how it should replace them with correct values.

Comment: What are you expecting `std::find_if` to pass in as the values?

Answer (score 3):

Your error message transcription misses the most interesting part: the error message!

Nevertheless, the problem seems obvious: the `find_if` function only needs one parameter, so you need to capture the `name`, that's what the `[]` are for:

```
auto it=find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),
    [&name](const HostName& a){return a==name;});
```

This [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) explains the lambdas quite well.

Comment: can u explain what  [&name] means?
if i have a func with more than one arg. 
 should i write  [&name, &other]

Comment: @user2975699: Sure: It is the capture list. That means that `name` from the outer scope will be available inside the lambda, with the same name. You can do `[name]` to copy the value into the lambda, or `[&name]` to get it by reference, that is without copying it. If you capture by reference, be careful that your lambda does not live longer than the captured value.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) expects  *unary* predicate. You are passing it a *binary* one:

```
auto it=find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),
                [](const HostName& a, const HostName& b){return a==b;});
```

This cannot work. It looks like this is what you really want:

```
auto it = std::find(v.begin(),v.end(), name);
```

Comment: But if i have unary predicate how can i then compare two things?

Comment: @user2975699, You're basically doing what's already in the loop of `std::find`. It uses `==` to compare the object it's on to the one it's looking for. If it helps at all, you can view a sample implementation of `std::find` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and see what it does for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need not to use `std::find_if`. It is enough to use `std::find`

Change thsi statement

```
 auto it=find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const HostName& a, const HostName& b){return a==b;});
```

to

```
 auto it=find( v.begin(),v.end(), name );
```

**EDIT**: I am sorry. I did not see that you defined the vector as

```
std::vector<std::pair<HostName,IPAddress> > v;
```

In this case you indeed need to use `std::find_if` with a lambda expression

```
auto it=find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                [&]( const std::pair<HostName,IPAddress>& a) { return a.first == name; } );
```

Also as member function `remove` has return type `bool` I would advice to use algorithm `std::any_of`
instead of `std::find_if`

For example

```
bool VNS::remove( const HostName &name )
{
   return any_of( v.begin(), v.end(), 
                  [&]( const std::pair<HostName,IPAddress>& a) { return a.first == name; } );    
}
```

Though if you need the target iterator inside the function then indeed it is better to use `std::find_if`

Also take into account that if you indeed removed an element from the vector you may not write after that

```
    if(it!=v.end()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

The valid code will be

```
bool found = it != v.end();
if ( found )
{
   // removing the element
}

return found;
```

The problem is that you provided a confusing example of code.:)

Answer (score 0):

to `find_if` you should pass a "predicate", i.e. a function taking one single parameter and returning `true`/`false`.

Replacing your lambda with

```
[&](const HostName& a){return a==name;}
```

should work as you expect.

That said as other noted however you can just pass the string to `find` instead of a predicate to `find_if` because `find` uses `operator==` anyway.